# Network address translation (NAT), C++

Tags: c++, linux, windows, networking

Is there a possible way so that you can create server-client communication, while both are behind multiple NATs/Private networks?
Lets say my server is behind multiple private networks:
[used tracert with ip of google.com to determine where are packets going](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrH38.png)

And my friend that i want to have client app is also behind multiple private networks, how can i get around this? Is there even possible way to get around it? If there is i prefer windows programming from linux but if you can explain only in linux its no problem.

Comment: You cannot program your way around NAT on a router or firewall. You should research STUN and TURN.